# Not adding Card Layout in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout

Can anyone see the code ? I want to make a page that has a banner and a pannel in which cards will change on the requirement. I added the Banner in JFrame (That is working fine) but The problem is that " CardLayout Panel is not adding in the JFrame".

[Actually, I need this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrE0G.png)

[image]

When button is pressed only card1 change to card2 but banner will remain same.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class gui extends JFrame{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JPanel  
    basic_panel,
    card_Layout_panel,
    banner_panel,
    welcome_authenticaion_panel_card1;

    CardLayout basic2;

    JLabel 
    logo_label,
    name_label;


    public gui(){

        server_login_gui();
        add(basic_panel);
        standard_gui(); 
    }

    public void server_login_gui(){


        basic_panel = new JPanel();
        basic_panel.setLayout(null);
        basic_panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 2));

        banner_panel = new JPanel();
        banner_panel.setLayout(null);
        banner_panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN, 2));
        banner_panel.setSize(680, 200);//(400,100,400,100);


        //////Banner inner things//////////////////////////////////////////////////
        logo_label = new JLabel("Logo");
        logo_label.setBounds(30,40,100,100);
        logo_label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.YELLOW, 2));
        banner_panel.add(logo_label);

        name_label = new JLabel("        Name.....   ");
        name_label.setFont(new Font("Times new Roman", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC,25));
        name_label.setBounds(200,80,400,50);
        name_label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.YELLOW, 2));
        banner_panel.add(name_label);
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////        

//          basic_panel.add(banner_panel,BorderLayout.NORTH);


        ///////// Card Layout//////////////
        basic2 = new CardLayout();
        card_Layout_panel = new JPanel(basic2);
        card_Layout_panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE, 5));
        basic_panel.add(card_Layout_panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        welcome_authenticaion_panel_card1 = new JPanel();
        welcome_authenticaion_panel_card1.setLayout(null);
        welcome_authenticaion_panel_card1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2));
        welcome_authenticaion_panel_card1.setSize(680, 200);//(400,100,400,100);
        welcome_authenticaion_panel_card1.setBounds(0,200,680,460);

        card_Layout_panel.add(welcome_authenticaion_panel_card1, "1");

        basic_panel.add(card_Layout_panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);


            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }

    public void standard_gui(){
        setSize(700,700);
        setTitle("System");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably because all of the null layouts... Since `basic_panel` has a null layout instead of a borderlayout, the constraints `BorderLayout.NORTH` and `BorderLayout.CENTER` won't do what you think they would. Also you should use another layout for the banner. Please see [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: Please see the MKorbel's code down. It is working fine without null layouts but I want to place each thing in its right position. How it is possible without null layout?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make a page that has a banner and a pannel in which cards
>   will change on the requirement.

1. your component aren't focusable, there is required some event (JButton, Swing Timer) for switching the view by using CardLayout
2. for more info about [CardLayout to read Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), for working code exampes, tons code examples are here
3. you code works without NullLayout (by set BorderLayout to parent JPanel), default LayoutManager for Jpanel is FlowLayout (accepts only getPreferredSize, childs aren't resizable with its parent/s)
4. my question is for why reason is there code line `basic_panel.add(card_Layout_panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);` twice, and another ...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Gui extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel basic_panel, card_Layout_panel,
            banner_panel, welcome_authenticaion_panel_card1;
    private CardLayout basic2;
    private JLabel logo_label, name_label;

    public Gui() {
        server_login_gui();
        add(basic_panel);
        standard_gui();
    }

    public void server_login_gui() {

        basic_panel = new JPanel();
        basic_panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
        basic_panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 2));
        banner_panel = new JPanel();
        //banner_panel.setLayout(null);
        banner_panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN, 2));
        banner_panel.setSize(680, 200);//(400,100,400,100);
        //////Banner inner things//////////////////////////////////////////////////
        logo_label = new JLabel("Logo");
        //logo_label.setBounds(30, 40, 100, 100);
        logo_label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.YELLOW, 2));
        banner_panel.add(logo_label);
        name_label = new JLabel("        Name.....   ");
        name_label.setFont(new Font("Times new Roman", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 25));
        //name_label.setBounds(200, 80, 400, 50);
        name_label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.YELLOW, 2));
        banner_panel.add(name_label);
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////      
        basic_panel.add(banner_panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        ///////// Card Layout//////////////
        basic2 = new CardLayout();
        card_Layout_panel = new JPanel(basic2);
        card_Layout_panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE, 5));
        basic_panel.add(card_Layout_panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        welcome_authenticaion_panel_card1 = new JPanel();
        welcome_authenticaion_panel_card1.setLayout(null);
        welcome_authenticaion_panel_card1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2));
        welcome_authenticaion_panel_card1.setSize(680, 200);//(400,100,400,100);
        //welcome_authenticaion_panel_card1.setBounds(0, 200, 680, 460);
        card_Layout_panel.add(welcome_authenticaion_panel_card1, "1");
        basic_panel.add(card_Layout_panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }

    public void standard_gui() {
        setSize(700, 700);
        setTitle("System");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Gui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It working in your way (Not null layouts) But I want to place each thing in its way as by null layouts. How can I do that?

Comment: Draw a layout that shows us exactly what you want, add it to your question, and we might be able to give you an answer.   Creating containers with absolutely positioned containers (null layouts) can cause problems if the window containing the container is resized

Comment: Picture is added above.

Answer (score 0):

you're doing this `basic_panel.add(card_Layout_panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);` twice, hence the error. ( check before and after the welcome_authentication_panel_card )

Comment: Please see the MKorbel's code above. It is working fine without null layouts but I want to place each thing in its right position. How it is possible without null layout?